# Remote Debugging won't connect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, animate-cc

I sort of make shift followed [this guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSd106d9f573d8da23-dcd13bd12a7d944d0b-7ffe.html) on how to setup remote debugging. Since I am using Adobe Animate to compile my app I assume it has done the majority of the build steps already as I get a similar screen described.

[image]

I don't understand though. Here I have port forwarding up on my router so that it goes to my PC. I have TCP port 7935 up and open. Windows firewall on or off doesn't seem to make difference. Windows firewall even prompted me to allow or deny fdb after I ran it. I can't get my phone to connect via remote debugging. I want to be able to send this to my client who is having issue with the app so I can see what's going on under the hood instead of relying on a giant sum of try/catch statements and screenshots. Any help?

I tried a dummy domain and it seems to know that it can't connect to it. When I try mine or my IPv4 it doesn't let me connect. It just freezes up the app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using Scout?

Comment: In your first [**picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI1lF.png) are those a ton of warnings about using **exact same** duplicate variable names for different data-types? Fix it since will cause other issues later on...

Comment: VC Yeah but It's only because I have a ton of for loops all using i in different functions. Nothing I'm worried about.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it works or not in Animate CC, but it works via Flash Builder. I'm using Android real device and I have Android SDK tools installed on my PC

Yes, I have followed that tuts from official Adobe docs, but that doesn't work

**First: Simply connect your device to your PC** 
Actually , you can debug your app remotely as long as your device has been connected with your PC. This step, doesn't necessarily requires FDB.
In my case , all I need was things like

```
adb connect 192.168.xx.xx:port
```

this will connect your Android device with your PC on your default network .

Second, set debug setting over network 

You've done it in Animate CC, with addition you might want to check "install application on the connected device'

Third, just debug as usual 

You can get all those debugging stuff including traces